# Получить доступ к глобальному объекту Vue из другого js-файла

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, quasar.js

Имеется проект на Quasar (VueJS) с использованием Axios.
В **boot.js** происходит инициализация axios

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
```

Затем я пытаюсь использовать этот объект в другом файле проекта **mutations.js**

```
export function getVendors (state) {
    this.$axios.post('/get_vendors.php')
        .then(response => { console.log(response) })
}
```

и получаю ошибку

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"
```

Пробую сделать через стрелочные функции

```
const getVendors = (state) => {
...
export { getVendors }
```

и ошибка следующая

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property '$axios' of undefined"
```

Очевидно, что содержание в объекте **this** в разных случаях своё, отличное от глобального объекта приложения.
Как получить доступ к глобальному объекту *Vue* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Иногда вы хотите получить доступ к данным, которые вы настраиваете в своем загрузочном файле (boot file), в файлах, где у вас нет доступа к корневому экземпляру Vue.
>
> К счастью, поскольку загрузочные файлы (boot files) являются просто обычными файлами JavaScript, вы можете добавить столько именованных экспортов в свой загрузочный файл, сколько захотите. Давайте возьмем пример `Axios`. Иногда вы хотите получить доступ к своему экземпляру `Axios` внутри файлов JavaScript, но не можете получить доступ к корневому экземпляру Vue. **Чтобы решить эту проблему, вы можете экспортировать экземпляр Axios в свой загрузочный файл и импортировать его в другое место.**

Пример boot file для Axios:

```
// axios boot file (src/boot/axios.js)

import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

// Мы создаем наш собственный экземпляр axios и устанавливаем собственный базовый URL
// Обратите внимание, что если бы мы не установили здесь никакой конфигурации, нам не нужно использовать
// именованный экспорт, так как мы могли бы просто `import axios из 'axios'`
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
})

// для использования внутри файлов Vue через this.$axios
Vue.prototype.$axios = axiosInstance

// Здесь мы определяем именованный экспорт
// чтобы мы могли позже использовать axios внутри .js файлов:
export { axiosInstance }
```

В **любом** файле JavaScript вы сможете импортировать экземпляр `axios` следующим образом.

```
import { axiosInstance } from 'boot/axios'
```

Больше информации по ссылке - [Quasar boot files: Доступ к данным из загрузочных файлов](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files#Accessing-data-from-boot-files)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

в начало файла **mutations.js** и использовать **Vue.prototype** вместо **this**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export function getVendors (state) {
  Vue.prototype.$axios.post('/get_vendors.php')
```

Это помогло. Но существует ли более правильный вариант ?

Comment: а ведь можно было просто подключить `axios` к `window` и использовать в любой части проекта без необходимости подключать `Vue`..

`import Axios from 'axios';`

`window.axios = Axios;`